# Non-ASCII attribute values in ElementTree

Tags: python, elementtree, non-ascii-characters

I have an XML file with non-ASCII chars as attribute values. A line like this:

```
photo = attributes.find("content[@type='写真']")
```

makes ElementTree complain about being unable to compare strings:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementPath.py:176:
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if elem.get(key) == value:
```

How to handle such attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Unicode path expressions:

```
photo = attributes.find(u"content[@type='写真']")
```

The `u` prefix on the string literal makes this a `unicode` object and no implicit decoding is required anymore.

Demo:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> sample = u'''\
... <root>
... <content type="写真">match</content>
... </root>
... '''.encode('utf8')
>>> tree = ET.fromstring(sample)
>>> tree.find("content[@type='写真']")
/.../lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementPath.py:176: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if elem.get(key) == value:
>>> tree.find(u"content[@type='写真']")
<Element 'content' at 0x10690da10>
```